# Star items in the Recent Folder

Tags: 22.04, context-menu

The right-click / context menu in the Recent folder doesn't have the "Star" option.  Any way that I can add this?

Comment: they are only links to recent files. If you right click on the file and select *Open Item Location* the actual file will be shown and you will be able to select *Star* from there.

Comment: @24601 Do not hesitate to turn that into an anwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are only links to recent files.

If you *right click* on the file and select *Open item Location* the actual file will be shown and you will be able to select *Star* from there